# How to make custom PowerShell Modules override programs in path?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I have a custom PowerShell 7 Module called `grep` located at `C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules\grep`.

In my system environment path, there is also a `grep.exe` installed through msys2.

When calling `grep` in the terminal, `grep.exe` from the path is invoked. However, I want to call the `grep` from the module. How can I do that?

```
PS C:\> Get-Command grep

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     grep.exe                                           0.0.0.0    C:\msys64\usr\bin\grep.exe
```

```
PS C:\> Get-Module -ListAvailable | where Name -EQ grep

    Directory: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                PSEdition ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                --------- ----------------
Script     0.0                   grep                                Desk      grep
```

Comment: The native command should be last in [order of precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-7.3) - what happens if you load your module before calling the command?  The docs say that PowerShell won't load it for you if a native command with the same name exists, but if you've already loaded it, it should use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[boxdog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9529842/boxdog) has provided the crucial pointers in a comment:

- Given PowerShell's [command precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Precedence), aliases, cmdlets, functions and, on Windows, even scripts (located in `$env:PATH`)<sup>[1]</sup> take precedence over *external programs* (executables).
- Therefore, once your module has been *imported*, it's `grep` command should preempt `grep.exe`.
- However, PowerShell's [auto-loading mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading) does *not* trigger import of modules containing a command with a given name, if a command with that name is *already available*, notably in the form of an *external program*.

In other words: **For your `grep` module's `grep` command to preempt `grep.exe`, you must ensure that your module has been imported first**.

To do that implicitly, as part of a single command, you can do the following, using a module-name *prefix*:

```
# Use module prefix 'grep\' to explicitly target a command in it.
# This automatically triggers the module's import, if not already loaded.
grep\grep ...
```

---

If you want to be able t**o use `grep` as-is to invoke your module function**, you must ensure that your module is imported first, which you can achieve in one of two ways, via your [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file (but note that profile loading can be bypassed via the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) with `-NoProfile`):

- *Unconditionally* import your module on startup:

  - Place the following in your `$PROFILE` file:

    ```
    Import-Module grep
    ```
- Define an *alias* on startup, which explicitly references the module function, as above, which triggers implicit importing only at the time the alias is first invoked in a session:

  - Place the following in your `$PROFILE` file:

    ```
    Set-Alias grep grep\grep
    ```

---

<sup>[1] On *Windows*, unless an `.exe` file is invoked *with its extension*, PowerShell gives precedence to `.ps1` files with a given (extension-less) name. On *Unix*-like platforms, where executables usually do *not* have filename extensions, the latter take precedence.</sup>